# Kendo UI Cascading DropDownList in MVVM does not bind data with auto selection

Tags: mvvm, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, cascading

I'm getting mad with this problem. The cascading dropdown is not binding data if the parent is selected and children are auto selected after that. here is my jsbin link. Anyone please help.
http://jsbin.com/ujorer/253/edit

Answer (score 0):

[I edited your fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/ujorer/267/edit) 
I set the values of the dropdowns to a default values and altered the alert function. Not sure if I really understood your question but hope this is a clue.

Comment: @Alan..Your fiddle did not help. My problem was that the child dropdown does not update it's value to the view model parameter it's bounded to..though it shows the changed text.